# System.Net.Http.Formatting missing in some machines(xml) but works in other (dll)

Tags: asp.net, dll, system.net.httpwebrequest

The best way to include System.Net.Http.Formatting might be through nuget. But when a developer sees it in the default Assemblies section in reference manager then they just add it, expecting all developers to have it installed by default. But to our surprise, some developer machines did not have this dll.

All developers have the correct folder where this dlls is found
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\"
Some developers just have XML files and others have dlls in it, even though the file names are the same.

Why are dlls missing in some machines?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is really an issue while finding the missing dlls. Better approach is to clean the nuget cache and folder both and restoring nuget packages again would resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

**System.Net.Http.Formatting mystery resolved**

System.Net.Http.Formatting won't be installed by default along with asp.net. If it appeared in one developer machine, then it could be because some other projects in the VS might have used a nuget to pull it in. This developer without knowing this gives a manual reference to this dll in a new/different project. To him/her everything works fine.

When another/new developer comes and tries to do the same in his/her machine, before reaching this particular project(which pulled in System.Net.Http.Formatting through nuget), the developer gets error(from the manually entered dll project by the previous developer mentioned above). That explains why the dll is missing in his/her machine.

**But why is XML file present then?**
Becuase the package folder was stored in tfs/git from the first developer machine(who successfully had the dll through nuget). And tfs/git ignored the dll when checked-in.